# Why is my picker in Xamarin.Forms not showing

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add a picker in my XAML code in Xamarin.Forms but strangely enough, it refuses to show up. Help please!

Here is my code;

```
<StackLayout>

    <Label Text="Welcome"
     VerticalOptions="Start"
     Margin="0,150,0,0"
     HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
     Rotation="0"
     IsVisible="true"
     FontSize="20"
     TextColor="Black"></Label>


    <Picker x:Name="IndustryTypePicker1" Title="Select">
        <Picker.Items>
            <x:String>1</x:String>
            <x:String>2</x:String>
        </Picker.Items>
    </Picker>


</StackLayout>
```

[image: Code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/)

> However, a Picker doesn't show any data when it's first displayed.
>
> When the Picker gains focus, its data is displayed and the user can select an item:

Comment: How can I make it gain focus to display the data?

Comment: You printed tha XAML previewer, this is a layout preview tool only... The problem you've describe occurs at device/emulator?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza so I can’t see the picker in the preview?

Comment: Yes, you can't see it there.

Comment: Oh...Ok then, thanks! So I have to buy a cheap Android phone to test my app? (I have an iPhone...but no Mac yet).

Comment: you can test in the Android emulator - but that is not the same thing as the XAML previewer

Comment: Hm...that just displays a black screen...any idea what's wrong?

Comment: do you have a MainPage assigned?

Comment: Yes I have assigned a MainPage.

Comment: Ok never mind I found an old Android; but question; do I have to rebuild everytime I make a small edit?